# Dúvida de como mensurar o número de palavras entre duas palavras especificas em uma string no R

Tags: r

Olá, Pessoas!

Eu estou trabalhando em uma função no R que mensure a quantidade de palavras entre duas palavras especificas, estou chamando a função de `worDistance`, ela funciona da seguinte maneira, você insere dois argumentos, dada uma string t, por exemplo, `palavra1` e `palavra2` e ela retorna o número de palavras entre a palavra 1 e palavra 2, por exemplo, dado que:

```
t <- "bom dia posso ajudar nao viu zunkz sabe tava pagar"

worDistance("bom","ajudar") # ela retorna o número 2.
```

Denote que a função lê a string t da esquerda para direita, quando eu inverto as ordem das palavras para

```
worDistance("ajudar","bom")
```

ela retorna o número `0`. Em vez de retornar `2`, novamente, como eu posso resolver isso??

Vou colocar a estrutura da função abaixo:

```
worDistance <- function( palavra1, palavra2 , direcao ) {#

###Legenda
#A função vai retornar "-1" quando uma das palavras inseridas no input não existir na string t
#A função vai retornar "-2" quando ambas as palavras inseridas no input não existir na string t



 if( direcao == 1 ) {##

    # 1 = Esquerda para direita

    total_palavras <- sapply(strsplit(transcricao, " "), length) 

    a <- gsub( paste0('^.*',palavra1,'\\s*|\\s*',palavra2,'.*$'), '', 
    transcricao)

    b <- sapply(strsplit(a, " "), length)

    if( b == total_palavras ) {

      return(-2)

    }else if( b == (total_palavras) - 1) {

      return(-1)

    }else if( b != total_palavras ){

      return(b)

    }

  }##

}#
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uma possibilidade é de usar o operador `%in%` para encontrar a posição da `palavra1` e da `palavra2` e então calcular a distância entre as duas:

```
t <- "bom dia posso ajudar nao viu zunkz sabe nao tava pagar"
frase <- unlist(strsplit(t, " "))
palavras <- c('dia', 'zunkz')

# posicao das palavras na frase
pos <- which(frase %in% palavras)
pos
# [1] 2 7

# calcular distância
diff(pos) - 1
# [1] 4
```

Observe que, mesmo se as palavras não estiverem na mesma ordem, a posição não irá mudar e então a distância pode ser facilmente calculada:

```
palavras <- c('zunkz', 'dia')
which(frase %in% palavras) # mesma posição que antes
# [1] 2 7
```

Você terá que ajustar a função para lidar com possíveis palavras repetidas, mas isso é sujeito de uma outra questão.